# (pydrake) How do I trace an input port back to its connected output port?

Tags: drake

I am implementing a small monitoring system to compute the error between (actual, desired) for a controller (and also recording them for quick and simple analysis). In some of my code, I've added my `System`s to my `DiagramBuilder` and have connected everything using `Connect()`.

I have a controller system that takes in desired input, then produces the actual as output.
Rather than try to remember the inputs connected to the desired output, I'd rather just trace it back.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

From quick perusal, there is both `DiagramBuilder.connection_map()` and `Diagram.connection_map()`.

The following code seems to work as of v1.11.0:

```py
def trace_to_output(diagram_or_builder, input_port):
    system = input_port.get_system()
    input_locator = (system, input_port.get_index())
    connection_map = diagram_or_builder.connection_map()
    output_system, output_index = connection_map[input_locator]
    output_port = output_system.get_output_port(output_index)
    return output_port
```

EDIT: I had `dict_inverse()` in there incorrectly. Fixed.